# Does $\operatorname{Int}D_{N+1}\subset A_{N+1}$ hold? ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.)

Tags: general-topology

I am afraid that I am asking a very stupid question.

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Let $d$ denote the sup metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, let $d(x,B)$ denote the distance from $x$ to $B$, as usual. (See section 4.)
> Now set $B=\mathbb{R}^n-A$. Then given a positive integer $N$, let $D_N$ denote the set $$D_N=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:d(x,B)\geq\frac{1}{N}\text{ and }d(x,0)\leq N\}.$$

> Finally, we note that the set $$A_{N+1}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:d(x,B)>\frac{1}{N+1}\text{ and }d(x,0)< N+1\}$$ is open (because $d(x,B)$ and $d(x,0)$ are continuous). Since $A_{N+1}$ is contained in $D_{N+1}$ and contains $D_N$ by definition, it follows that $D_N\subset\operatorname{Int}D_{N+1}$.

If $O$ is open and $O\subset S$, then $O\subset\operatorname{Int}S$.
The author used this fact.

In general, when $O$ is open and $O\subset S$, $\operatorname{Int}S\subset O$ doesn't hold.
But I wonder $\operatorname{Int}D_{N+1}\subset A_{N+1}$ holds.
Does $\operatorname{Int}D_{N+1}\subset A_{N+1}$ hold?

The author didn't write $\operatorname{Int}D_{N+1}= A_{N+1}$ holds because this equality doesn't hold?

Or the author didn't write $\operatorname{Int}D_{N+1}= A_{N+1}$ but this equality holds? (The author didn't write unnecessary information?)

---

Let $S_1:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:d(x,0)\leq N+1\}$.
Then, $\operatorname{Int}S_1=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:d(x,0)< N+1\}$ holds.

Let $S_2:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:d(x,B)\geq \frac{1}{N+1}\}$.
Then, does $\operatorname{Int}S_2=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:d(x,B)>\frac{1}{N+1}\}$ hold?